# How to change the data type of column of a Dataframe from float to int which has NaN values in it?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

**This is not a duplicate. All other question, you have to set `dtype='Int64'` or `pd.Int64Dtype()` while constructing the `DataFrame`**

I have a dataframe with a column name `score` which has `float,Nan` values in it. I want to change the type to int. I have used

```
pd.to_numeric(df['score'], errors='coerce')
df['score'].map(int)
df['score'].astype('Int64')
```

but none of the methods seems to work on it. I know I can convert the `NaN` values to some other value, convert and then again change values but it is such a bad practice. Is there any good method to do it?

Comment: In the code you posted, you don't assign the outputs to anything. Please provide a [mcve] showing how and if you assigned the output back to the column

Comment: Granted, this uses `.replace()`, however the logic works.  Is this acceptable?  `df.replace(np.NaN, 0).round().astype(np.int64)`.  If no, I'll delete the comment.  If yes, I'll post the full content as an answer.  I believe that due to `pandas` logic, an `NaN` value cannot be converted directly to an `int` value.

Comment: Your code does not do anything to the original dataframe without reassigning. Di you try `df['score'] = df['score'].astype('Int64')`?

Comment: What you are looking for is [`nullable integer type`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html) which is new since `pandas >= 0.24`

Comment: @QuangHoang yes, I tried everything and the result is ```cannot safely cast non-equivalent float64 to int64 ```.

Comment: @G.Anderson I want to print it out on the jupyter notebook for starters but I did it ```x=df['score'].astype('Int64')```. Did not work!

Comment: @Erfan did it already but does not seem to work. They only talk about the declaring its value while constructing the DataFrame for the time. After that, it's a mystery

Answer (score 0):

You can try this..

```
import numpy as np

df['score'].replace('nan', np.nan).fillna(0)
```

Comment: To aid readability, please format your answer correctly, using code blocks.